# Use of an exclamation mark in a Git commit message via the command line

Tags: git, bash

How do I enter an exclamation point into a Git commit message from the command line?

It is possible to escape the exclamation point with a backslash, but then the backslash ends up in the commit message as well.

I want something like this:

```
git commit -am "Nailed it!"
```

Comment: For an explanation of why this problem exists in the first place: http://askubuntu.com/questions/434832/why-does-exclamation-mark-within-double-quotes-cause-a-bash-error

Comment: *It is possible to escape the exclamation point with a backslash, but then the backslash ends up in the commit message as well.* I've noticed that behaviour as well when using `grep`. I can't make sense of it!

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes

```
git commit -am 'Nailed it!'
```

Alternatively, if you need to use double quotes for whatever reason but still want a literal `!` then turn off history expansion at the top of your script via `set +H`

Comment: Or just mix your quotes: `git commit -am "$FOO: Nailed it"'!'`

Comment: This wasn't working for me in OS X, so I just used `git commit` (no -m) to open up a text editor for my message.

Comment: In OSX use `git commit -m "This is the best code ever"!` as described in @Ryan H. answer.

Answer (score 52):

Another way to solve that is to add a *space* after *!* like:

```
git commit -am "Nailed it! "
```

Note the *space* between *!* and the last *"*.

(The space won't be included in the commit message - Git trims trailing whitespace from commit messages automatically.)

Comment: This seems the simplest solution to me, and allows double-quotes with variable interpolation: `git commit -m "$(sillyname) $(buzzphrase). $(superb)! "` :)

Comment: I'm so upset with myself for not googling for an answer to this ages ago. I had no idea it would be such a simple solution. My commit messages deserved the excitement I was trying to bring to them! 

Answer (score 8):

If you need to use double quotes and the `!` is the last character in the message, [just keep the `!` outside of the quotes](https://willi.am/blog/2014/05/22/escaping-exclamation-marks-in-bash/), since we're only using quotes so that the spaces get included in the message.

```
git commit -m "Reverting last commit because I don't like it"!
```

If you need to include `!` mid string, you can use single quotes but if you need to use a literal single quote, you'll need to close your quote, then put the `'` outside of the string by escaping it. So, let's say your message is `I don't like it! Reverting again!`, this can be composed with `'I don'` + `\'` + `'t like it! Reverting again!'`

```
git commit -m 'I don'\''t like it! Reverting again!'
```

Anything more complicated than this, you're probably better off with `git commit` and letting git invoke your default text editor :)

Answer (score 6):

No need to remember what quotes or escapes to use, instead

1. Type your command (or part of it)
2. In your command line, press
   `Ctr` `X` `E` » will open your "external editor".
3. Edit your command, and close your editor.

… the command will be executed &
any special characters will show up correctly in the Git commit message!

(NB many other uses: typing complex commands, adding line breaks in your commit message etc.)

Comment: this is a really useful shortcut, thanks! Works great on MacOS!

Answer (score 1):

You can also type:

```
git commit -am "Nailed it
!
"
```

So just hit enter and place the exclamation mark on a new line, then close off the commit message. Found that one out by accident one day.

Comment: This will insert the literal newline prior to the exclamation mark into the commit message, which is ugly. -1.

Answer (score -2):

Hmm. Escaping it with a slash doesn't show up in commit message for me.

```
git commit -m "Nailed it\!"
```

Comment: The backslashes did show up in my commit messages, but thanks