# Can't add the "!" symbol in my git commit message

Tags: git, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enter an exclamation point into a git commit message from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131948/how-do-i-enter-an-exclamation-point-into-a-git-commit-message-from-the-command-l)

I'm new to git, and I did this command:

```
git commit -m "First Commit!"
```

This throws an error like this:

```
bash: !": event not found
```

Why is this error happening? Is is that in Git, I shouldn't use `!` symbols in `commit`?

Are there other symbols which I shouldn't use or should escape with any escape sequence?

Comment: You might find this useful: http://superuser.com/questions/133780/in-bash-how-do-i-escape-an-exclamation-mark.

Comment: sorry I searched with "Git adding !", but didn't get relevant results..

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Nothing to do with git, more to do with bash - escape the `!` or use single quotes, i.e.

```
$ git commit -m "First Commit\!"
```

or, better:

```
$ git commit -m 'First Commit!'
```

Comment: Escaping with a backslash as in your first method will leave an unsightly literal backslash in the actual commit message. The answer on [the post this is a dupe of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131948/use-of-an-exclamation-mark-in-a-git-commit-message-via-command-line) is better.

Comment: FYI for someone who does not want to manually escape characters. Another approach is to use `git gui` command in terminal. then we can use the commit message without needing to manually escape the characters

Answer (score 12):

That's not git related at all, but bash related. Using ! in a string will cause bash to attempt history expansion. If you don't want that, either use single-quoted strings or escape the exclamation mark with a backslash.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is possible in with the git command line and double quotes. One easy fix is putting a space after `!`.

```
git commit -m "First Commit! "
```

Another way to get around this is by using `git gui` or just `git commit` and then specifying the message in the editor that opens.

The limitation is clearly a bash limitation and not a problem of git. You can avoid it using single quotes:

```
git commit -m 'First Commit!'
```

Comment: It's not a *limitation*, it's a *feature* !

Comment: Not true, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5131960/298389): it is possible, just use single quotes