# Weird message on .git commit with exclamation point

Tags: macos, git, terminal

So here's a REALLY odd one that i've never seen before. When ever I commit with an un-escaped exclamation point I get a really odd message...

```
git commit -am "New stuff!"
```

the result is something like...

```
git commit -am "New stuff"why dont you go back to Philadelphia?"
>
```

I have a custom bash profile but I can't figure out why it's giving me this damn message and how I can find it and change/delete it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use of an exclamation mark in a Git commit message via command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5131948/use-of-an-exclamation-mark-in-a-git-commit-message-via-command-line)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exclamation mark `!` has a special meaning to bash - it triggers history substitution.

To use the exclamation mark in a commit message, escape it using `\`:

```
git commit -am "New stuff\!"
```

or use single quotation marks (which prevent most kinds of substitution):

```
git commit -am 'New stuff!'
```

See the Bash Reference Manual, chapter ["9.3.1 Event Designators"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Event-Designators).

Comment: Thanks so much! is there any way I can change/delete this message incase it happens again? I know it seems minor but I shared my bash profile with a few people and I know they'll probably get it as well.

Comment: @GThompson: I'm not sure where this message comes from, but if it's from your Bash history, it should be in ~/.bash_history. Try to look there.